# MySQL Not unique table/alias

Tags: mysql, table-alias

I looked at the answers of others having the same problem, but I can't figure out how to fix the "Not unique table/alias".

```
SELECT m.*, u.*
  FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."users_medals u
  LEFT JOIN ".TABLE_PREFIX."medals m ON u.medal_id = m.medal_id
  WHERE u.user_id IN (".$post['uid'].")
  AND m.medal_level = (
    SELECT MAX(".TABLE_PREFIX."medals.medal_level) FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."medals
    LEFT JOIN ".TABLE_PREFIX."medals ON ".TABLE_PREFIX."users_medals.medal_id = ".TABLE_PREFIX."medals.medal_id
    WHERE ".TABLE_PREFIX."users_medals.user_id = u.user_id
    AND ".TABLE_PREFIX."medals.medal_type = m.medal_type
  )
```

`TABLE_PREFIX` is what my script uses to define the database table prefix.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL & PHP - Not unique table/alias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077355/mysql-php-not-unique-table-alias)

Comment: Where exactly are you looking for the non-unique table/alias?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your sub-query

> LEFT JOIN ".TABLE_PREFIX."medals

I think that should be

```
LEFT JOIN ".TABLE_PREFIX."users_medals
```

Answer (score 0):

In the subquery you have two `medals` tables without aliases. I think the `FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."medals` should be `FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."users_medals`:

```
SELECT m.*, u.*
  FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."users_medals u
  LEFT JOIN ".TABLE_PREFIX."medals m ON u.medal_id = m.medal_id
  WHERE u.user_id IN (".$post['uid'].")
  AND m.medal_level = (
    SELECT MAX(".TABLE_PREFIX."medals.medal_level) FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."users_medals
    LEFT JOIN ".TABLE_PREFIX."medals ON ".TABLE_PREFIX."users_medals.medal_id = ".TABLE_PREFIX."medals.medal_id
    WHERE ".TABLE_PREFIX."users_medals.user_id = u.user_id
    AND ".TABLE_PREFIX."medals.medal_type = m.medal_type
  )
```